# Remove Top Shadow By Notification Bar in Android

Tags: android, themes, shadow, android-notification-bar

How can I remove the shadow by the notification bar?

[image]

**Themes.xml**

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="ExposureTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_background_image</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/ExposureTheme.TabWidget</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExposureTheme.TabWidget" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I was going to answer: add `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` - but then I saw you already have it set. Or is it on the second style (which could inherit from the first one)?

Comment: Its is set so that wouldnt be it